# table() within as.formula() using paste() in R function

Tags: r, function, chi-squared

I am working with the following data set

```
hsb2 <- within(read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv"), {
  race <- as.factor(race)
  schtyp <- as.factor(schtyp)
  prog <- as.factor(prog)
})
```

I wish to write a higher-order function to perform statistical tests on categorical dependet variables (such as chi square or Fisher).

As an example I am running these two tests:

```
chisq.test(table(hsb2$female, hsb2$schtyp))
chisq.test(table(hsb2$race, hsb2$schtyp))
```

I define my higher-order function as so:

```
multi.tests.categorical <- function(fun = chisq.test, df, vars, group.var, ...) {
      sapply(simplify = FALSE,                                    
             vars,                                                
             function(var) {
               formula <- as.formula(paste("table(",var, ",", group.var,")")) # create a formula with outcome and grouping var.
               fun(data = df, formula, ...)                     # perform test with a given fun, default t.test
             }
      )
    }
```

I then apply my higher order function in one block of code:

```
res.multi.chisq.tests <-
  multi.tests.categorical(fun = chisq.test,
              df = hsb2,
              vars = "schtyp",
              group.var = c("female","race"))
res.multi.chisq.tests
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Error in table(schtyp, female) : object 'schtyp' not found

I suspect that my use of table() within as.formula is perhaps the cause of this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorize solution could be

```r
#sample data
hsb2 <- within(read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv"), {
  race <- as.factor(race)
  schtyp <- as.factor(schtyp)
  prog <- as.factor(prog)
})

schtyp_idx <- match("schtyp", colnames(hsb2))
col_idx <- match(c("female", "race"), colnames(hsb2))
chisq.test_resultList = mapply(function(x,y){chisq.test(table(hsb2[,x],hsb2[,y]))}, schtyp_idx, col_idx)
chisq.test_resultList
```

Comment: @ykl pls don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem or a showstopper is still there...

Comment: Thank you for answer Prem, your solution does work with the code you specified. However, when I try to implement it in my "multi.tests.categorical" function, it does not seem to work as I new get error codes "Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :   object 'group.var1' of mode 'function' was not found. Could you please specify how you would implement your solution within the higher-roder multi.tests.categorical? Thanks.

Comment: With this solution you don't require your higher order function. You just need to include more columns in `col_idx` to have its Chi-squared test e.g. `col_idx <- match(c("female", "race", "<other_column_name>"), colnames(hsb2))`.